# How can I remove the navbar from React-Admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, next.js, react-admin

I'm having some issues trying to delete/remove the default navbar from react-admin.

[image]

As you can see, my original Navbar is at the bottom of the react-admin navbar
which if I inspect and remove it, it will look something like this:

[image]
The Post, Account, and the profile icon get pushed down. This was only when I removed the whole class of the blue navbar. What you see here is what I actually want to achieve.

This is my code so far: **dashboard.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { requireAuth } from 'util/auth.js';
import users from '../users';
import posts from '../posts';

// Initialize the dataProvider before rendering react-admin resources.
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';

function DashboardPage(props) {

  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <Resource name="Post" {...posts} />
      <Resource name="User" {...users} />
    </Admin>
  );
}

export default requireAuth(DashboardPage);
```

And this is my **_app.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "components/Navbar";
import Footer from "components/Footer";
import { AuthProvider } from "util/auth.js";
import { ThemeProvider } from "util/theme.js";
import { QueryClientProvider } from "util/db.js";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <AuthProvider>
          <>
            <Navbar
              color="default"
              logo="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/someRandomLogo"
            />

            <Component {...pageProps} />

            <Footer
              bgColor="light"
              size="normal"
              bgImage=""
              bgImageOpacity={1}
              description="Footer admin"
              sticky={true}
            />
          </>
        </AuthProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

I've been trying to add `display:none;` but this does not work, because logging in and out makes the blue navbar appears, which I don't want. I'll appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Admin` component has the `layout` property so it is possible to override existing layout including existing navigation.

```
 <Admin layout={CustomLayout} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
  <Resource name="Post" {...posts} />
  <Resource name="User" {...users} />
</Admin>

import { Layout } from 'react-admin';

const CustomLayout = (props) => <Layout
{...props}
appBar={null}
```

/>;

For example, if you don't want to display existing navigation you can pass `null` as value of the prop called `appBar`.
On the other side if you want to create your custom navigation then you just need to assign your custom navigation(component) as the value of `appBar` prop.

I hope it suggestion could be helpful.